# SVN to Git migration Commit history Issue

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, git-svn

I have a badly structured SVN repo. Let me try to give you an image.

```
svn-repo
|
|--branches
|     |
|     |-- project1
|     |-- project2
|     |-- tragetProject
|               |
|               |-- targetProject5.0.0
|               |-- targetProject5.0.1
|               |-- targetProject5.0.2
|               |-- ...
|
|--trunk
      |
      |-- project1
      |-- project2
      |-- ...
```

The project I want to migrate is the "targetProject". Each branch is derived from the latest branch, eg. 5.0.1 is a branch from 5.0.0. So each branch in svn has the commit history of it's ancestor.

This is the process I tried in order to migrate to git.

```
git svn init [trargetProject5.0.2 Url]
git svn fetch
```

My issue is that although the svn branch has all commit history, after fetch, in git local master there is only the commit history of this branch and not of it's ancestors.

I need to get all history. I tried changing the git branch url in git config in order to fetch the commits for each branch but this also failed as "git svn rebase" did not work as expected. I also need to get new commits of a maybe new branch created in svn repo. Can anybody help or provide me a new way to deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have found the solution.

Instead of cloning the trunk of my huge repo I wanted to clone a certain branch. So using this command does the trick.

```
git svn clone -T branches/tragetProject/tragetProject5.0.2 http://example.com/PROJECT
```

This will clone the current branch and also search each parent for all commit history.

Because my svn repo is huge and all branches are linked together this command would take ages to complete and would fetch unwanted commits from legacy branches. By adding  `-r<revision>:HEAD` at the end you limit the clone investigation to certain revision.

So the the command becomes:

```
git svn clone -T branches/tragetProject/tragetProject5.0.2 http://example.com/PROJECT -r40000:HEAD
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

> ref https://gist.github.com/trodrigues/1023167#file-gistfile1-txt-L30

Answer (score 1):

To migrate SVN to Git while keeping all the histories, you can use the command:

```
git svn clone <svn-repo URL> --branches=branches --tags=tags --trunk=trunk
```

Now all the commit histories are kept in git repo. By default, there only has the local branch `master`, but you can find other branches by `git branch -r`.

And the output of `git branch -r` command looks like `origin/branch1`. Then what you just need to do is checkout all the branches locally by `git branch -b <local Branch name> <remote branchname>`.

As the example above, to checkout `branch1` locally, you can use the command `git checkout -b branch1 origin/branch1`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I will try this.. But this is going to clone every project right? My problem is that the svn structure is bad and contains many different projects and the one I want to transfer is under the branches folder in the svn repo. Also the project I want to transfer has a new branch for each version. Do you recommend cloning the whole repo and then create a new branch merging the svn branches I need?

Comment: @itdoesntwork do you means only clone a certain branch instead of all the branches, then you can specify it in `--branches` option. Such as `--branches=branches\tragetProject`.